# C# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character with a date time picker

Tags: c#

I am creating a library management system.
For the date, I have a date picker and after I click the button save, it throws this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

This is where the error is:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into books_info values('"
                  + textBox1.Text        + "', '"
                  + textBox2.Text        + "', '"
                  + textBox3.Text        + "', '"
                  + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', "
                  + textBox5.Text        + ", "
                  + textBox6.Text        +
                ")";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: The text version of date/time picker cannot be directly converted by the database. For example, the dateTimePicker1.Text value might look like "January 17, 2020" whereas the database needs a format like "01/17/2020"

Comment: There is no need to convert a `DateTimePicker` selection ever.  `DateTimePicker.Value` ***is*** a `DateTime` type

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide us with an example of what `dateTimePicker1.Text` evaluates to?

Comment: Also, tagging this with the appropriate database (I assume it's SQL Server, but it could be ... just about anything else. DB2? Oracle? something else?)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles for details on what date/time styles SQL Server supports. And the default may be different, depending on (1) your locale, and (2) how your SQL Server instance was configured by your DBA team.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would be much safer and will probably also fix your error:

```
string commandText = "insert into books_info values(@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5, @val6)";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", textBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", textBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", textBox3.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", textBox5.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6", textBox6.Text);

    //OR DO THIS INSTEAD. SEE COMMENTS ON WHY AddWithValue IS NOT ALWAYS THE BEST CHOICE. 
    //FOR THIS, THE SQL TYPES AND FIELD LENGTHS SHOULD MATCH WHAT YOU ARE USING IN YOUR 
    //  DATABASE AND APPLICATION.
    command.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = textBox1.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = textBox2.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = textBox3.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val4", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = textBox5.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@val6", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64).Value = textBox6.Text;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @JohnWu that is good to know. Thank you. It is rare that I write manual DB connections like this, but I'll make a note to avoid AddWithValue when possible.